# What part of speech is "not" when it takes the place of a conjunction?

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

What part of speech is "not" in the following sentences, and why?

> I made him do it, not her.

> To solve a linear system neatly is only the primary and most straightforward use of the matrix, not its only use.

> It’s at eight o’clock, not nine.

If "not" here is an adverb, then where is the verb or adjective it modifies?  If "not" here is a conjunction, then why does it require a comma to precede it?

Or is "not" just a special case that breaks the ordinary rules of English grammar?

(For information, the first of the three examples is taken from [an answer to a related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/336177/25823) on this site, the second was written years ago by me, and the third is from [*dictionary.cambridge.org.*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is  a grammatical context of asyndetic coordination and use of ellipsis.

> I made him do it, not her.

- I made him do it and (I did) not (make) her (do it).

> (**CoGEL § 13.42**)
> **Note**
> [d] There is a type of repudiatory coordination *and not* . . . in which the relation between the
> clauses is the reverse of that of *not. . . but* described above : *He came to help, and not to hinder us*.
> In this type, where the negative occurs in the second conjoin, a repudiatory force can also be
> expressed asyndetically, by omitting the coordinator: *He came to help, not to hinder us*.

> (**CoGEL § 13.44**)   **Ellipsis and simple coordination**
>
> There are two different ways of examining simple coordination of clause
> constituents. On the one hand, we may examine a construction as an elliptical
> version of clause coordination, noting what elements are ellipted; and on the
> other hand, we may examine the construction in terms of the conjoins
> themselves-*viz* the elements which are left intact. These two different
> approaches are reflected in different principles of analysis. For example, the
> coordinate construction in :
>
> - They have already [finished their work] and ○ [gone home]. [1]
>
> can be viewed as a clause coordination in which a subject, operator, and
> adverbial have been ellipted; or it can be viewed as a single clause containing
> two coordinate predications. For simple coordination (though less so for
> other kinds of coordination) there are advantages in adopting the latter
> method as the major one […]. Thus in [1] we shall be interested in the fact that the conjoins (marked here […] by square brackets) are predications, and less interested in what elements have been omitted at the point marked by the symbol ○
>
> <sub>**Note**     
> We regard ellipsis as a relation of systematic correspondence […] between sentences. We therefore do not consider the explanations of [1] in terms of ellipsis and in terms of coordination of clause constituehts as in competition with one another. Rather, they are complementary accounts: one focusing on sentence structure, and the other on intersentential relations […]</sub>

In the first sentence ("I made him…"), have been ellipted, the subject ("I"), the operator ("did"), the verb form ("make do"), and the object ("it").

Comment: 'I made him do it, not her' would also often be used for 'I made him do it ... _she_ didn't'. // Is _not_'s POS actually suggested here? Or is 'and not' termed a compound 'repudiatory coordinator'?

Comment: "There is a type of repudiatory coordination and not . . . in which the relation between the clauses is the reverse of that of not. . . but described above : He came to help, and not to hinder us."  Yes, for two clauses. But: I made him do it, not her. **Is not two clauses**.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought about that possibility which is subject to context, but in the end decided not to mention it because of the idea that it could be considered by most as non-standard English. // There is no new definition of "not" as a part of speech, in my opinion, nor a definition of "and not" as one, but instead a categorization of a construction with "and". I am aware of no such term as "repudiatory coordinator", at least it doesn't appear in the texts of this grammar, however, the term "repudiatory construction" does figure in it, which is not surprising.

Comment: @Lambie "I told them, not him." can be viewed either as "I told them and not him." or as "I told them and I did not tell him.". This is what the grammar says. It follows that this dual analysis  is true for "I made him do it, not her.". You can view this construction as containing a verbless clause in which the verb has bee ellipted. ("I made him do it, (and) I did not make her do it.")

Comment: Where does *You not I will answer this* fall?

Comment: @tchrist I'd say that a comma is more likely after "you". Off hand, bar the idea of an analysis through cataphoric ellipsis ("You will answer this, not I…"), I have no certitude. It's an interesting question that you might put to the ELU.

Comment: I've seen 'not' ascribed its very own POS tag ('negativiser'), though the author didn't examine non-central occurrences. Prototypical of course are 'I am not hungry,' 'He does not snore.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't relate to this addition of a new part of speech; I presume that they are not speaking merely about a type of adverb and that they founded their determination of this new concept on the recognition of some incidence of pure logic into language. However, I fail to see anything more than an adverbial characterization in for instance "not fast"; to me, it excludes "very fast" and "extremely fast" and so on, and provides a new adverbial characterization which is open to further precisions to be determined from the context (slow, very slow, not very fast, and so on).

Comment: The author I refer to sees intensifiers/downtoners (very, slightly ...), including those with semantic content (terrifyingly, gratifyingly ... piping, finger-lickin' ...) as being so far from traditional adverbs as to need reclassification ('modifier of adjective'; 'modifier of adverb').